# Element, wind melds worth it to reach minimum han requirement?

Tags: mahjong, riichi-mahjong, yaku

Just wanting to confirm whether I'm understanding these rules correctly. The rule set from which I'm deriving most of my (Rīchi-)Mahjong knowledge only has this short paragraph about tiles being worth *han*:

> 三元牌、圏風牌、門風牌を飜牌とし、その刻子、槓子組ごとに一飜とする。
>   連風牌はニ飜とする。

Which I translate to:

> Elements tiles, prevailing wind tiles and player wind tiles are han tiles, with each triple or quad meld of them being worth one han.
>   Double wind tile melds are worth two han.

In a game with a one-han minimum requirement, does this mean if I have *any* element meld or a meld of any of the two relevant wind types, I can complete my hand? Meaning, it may be worth it to make a call for these tiles and opening my hand, even if the rest of my hand is not really worth much?

Comment: Just to clarify, standard riichi mahjong has a one-yaku minimum to go out, not a one-han minimum.  The difference between yaku and han is subtle, but important (dora and ura-dora provide han, but they are not yaku).

Comment: @gold That may be a difference in translation. The above rule set uses the term "han pai" and that these are worth one/two han. I also think the rule that specifies the minimum requirement also says han. I couldn't say whether this rule set is typical or necessarily the best though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

> **Yakuhai (役牌)**, also known as **Fanpai (飜牌)**, is a 1-han yaku consisting of a pon/kan of any of the following:
>
> - Dragons (elements)
> - Your current seat wind
> - The current round wind (typically east or south)

As it is a yaku, it will net you the 1-yaku minimum required to complete your hand.  It doesn't matter if the hand remains open or closed, so calling a discarded tile to complete the set is perfectly legal.

Whether it is the best choice in any circumstance is highly dependent on the rest of your hand; the point value of an open set is only half that of a closed set, and there are many other potential yaku which are unavailable when a hand is opened.  In particular, you lose out on the ability to call riichi, which would also provide the 1-yaku minimum and give you a chance for ura-dora as well.

Comment: Is this quoted from somewhere? If so, could you link to the source?

Comment: @ire_and_curses: It's not a quote, I just used the notation for aesthetics so it would stand out